# Change menu background color for material design on api 8

Tags: android, material-design

I am an Android newbie and have written my first app that uses an action bar and the design support library. However when I expand the menu, it has a black background color. Before I applied material design, the menu had the default gray color. I don't have any dark color in my colors.xml file. How can I get the normal color back?
Below is the theme I created in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>            
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>            
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>            
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>            
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColorSecondary</item>           
    </style>
```

When I remove the app theme in my toolbar, I get the normal color back, but the action bar text and the color of the 3 vertical dots changes to black. Below are the relevant parts of my activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just to make sure, did you add your theme to Android manifest?

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar: Yes. Apptheme is the default manifest theme. I overwrote the existing theme with my own settings.

Comment: this may not help but try to change the parent to parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: @AbdullahAsendar: It does affect the menu background color. I have updated my question.

Comment: you have app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" ,,, in your android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ,, thats not possible !

Comment: What can be done? Vivz/slidenerd uses the same thing in his tutorial at http://slidenerd.com/2015/07/22/android-design-support-library/

Comment: you want a toolbar and tabs am i right ? if yes i was working on that couple of days ago and had all kinds of problems but it worked at the end so i can help

Comment: I do. I have the tabs already. Adding the action bar properly is the challenge I'm facing. What tutorial/resource would you recommend?

Comment: hope this will help : http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html
__________
http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html
____ both worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple. To change the background of the action bar popup menu, you add the following attribute to the `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` tag

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

You can use the default style or create your own with even more specific colors.